# Extending an old Monthly problem

Tags: number-theory

Monthly Problem 11781 (published in May 2014) says the following:

> For $n\ge 2$, call a positive integer $n$-smooth if none of its prime factors is larger than $n$. Let $S_n$ be the set of all $n$-smooth positive integers. Let $C$ be a finite, non-empty set of NON-NEGATIVE integers, and let $a$ and $d$ be positive integers. Let $M$ be the set of all positive integers of the form $m=\sum_{k=1}^d c_ks_k$ where $c_k\in C$
>   and $s_k\in S_n$ for $k=1,\ldots,d$. Prove that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p^a\notin M$.

Does the statement hold if also NEGATIVE numbers $c_k$ are allowed?